# Discrete Math - Determine if the argument is valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Can you guys please check my work and syntax.

Question: Determine if the argument is valid.

p $\rightarrow $ q 
$\underline{\urcorner{q}}$ 
$\therefore \urcorner$p

Answer: 
T $\rightarrow $ T 
$\underline{{F}}$ 
$\therefore$ F

Comment: So, is it valid or not? What's the definition of a valid argument?

Comment: @Demosthene I left out the important part - apologies. From what I have the conclusion is invalid because p and q are not both true in the argument. Therefore the conclusion is the argument is invalid. Sound / look correct?

Comment: An argument is valid if and only if its conclusion can never be false while its premises are true. In your example, notice that the premises are not $p$/$q$, but $p\to q$ and $\neg q$. The question is then, can you find a way to make $p\to q$ and $\neg q$ both true, but $\neg p$ false? If you can, then the argument is invalid; if you can't, then the argument is valid.

Comment: Always think about possible examples. For instance, take $p$ is "it has rained" and $q$ is "the ground is wet". Then, assuming it is true that "if it has rained, then the ground is wet", if I see that "the ground is not wet", I can deduce that "it has not rained".
This is known as the *law of contraposition*: $(A\to B)\to(\neg B\to\neg A)$.

Comment: @Demosthene you gave me alot to think about. I rewrote my truth table I see that if p $\rightarrow$ q are both false, then the $\urcorner$q becomes true therefore p $\rightarrow$ q (F $\rightarrow$ F = TRUE), both are then true evaluations making the argument valid. Or am I still missing it?

Comment: Your comment is a bit ambiguous, and I'm not sure I totally understand it. But you've found the solution, which is that if $p$ and $q$ are both false, then $p\to q$ is true, $\neg q$ is true and $\neg p$ is true, meaning that the argument is valid. That is, the only way to have both premises true at the same time is to have $p$ and $q$ both false, which in turns makes the conclusion true. Or in other words, there is no way to have the premises true and the conclusion false at the same time, therefore the argument is valid.

Comment: Do you need me to write a proper answer, or is that ok?

Comment: @Demosthene to be honest it would help because all I have is this book and my instructor hasnt replied in 3 days. (dam online school) In any case I'd appreciate it, doing my best over here you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step 1 : Definition of a valid argument

An argument is **valid** if and only if **its conclusion  is never false while its premises are true**.

### Step 2 : Building the truth table

We follow the standard method, enumerating all possible binary cases for the sentence letters $p$ and $q$, and apply the usual boolean operators to find the truth values of the premises of the argument (columns 3 and 4) and of its conclusion (column 5).

\begin{array}{cc|ccc}p&q&p\to q&\neg q&\neg p\\\hline T&T&T&F&F\\T&F&F&T&F\\F&T&T&F&T\\F&F&T&T&T\end{array}

### Step 3 : Interpretation of the truth table and conclusion

The only assignment of truth values to the sentence letters $p$ and $q$ that make both premises true is given in the last line of the truth table, i.e. when both $p$ and $q$ are false. In this configuration, the conclusion is also true.

We have shown that it is never the case that the premises are true while the conclusion is false, therefore, by definition, the **argument is valid**.

Comment: thanks for this great info.

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused about the very definition of a valid argument:

> An argument is *valid* iff whenever its premises are true, so is its conclusion.

In your approach, you took $p$ and $q$ to be the premises. However, this is not quite true. In  the given form:

$A$
$\underline{B}$
$C$

$A$ and $B$ are the premises, and $C$ is the conclusion. In the present case, we need to find all possible truth values for $p$ and $q$ so that both the premises $p \to q$ and $\neg q$ are true. Subsequently we need to check if the conclusion, in casu $\neg p$, is also true.

Basically, the only way that this could possibly fail would be if we took $q = F$ false (so that $\neg q$ is true) and at the same time $\neg p$ would be false, i.e. $p = T$.

However, if $p = T$ and $q = F$, then the first premise $p \to q$ is false.

Therefore, we are led to the conclusion that it is impossible to derive a false conclusion from true premises using this argument. I.e., that the argument is valid.

Comment: thanks to you also. Learning this w/ no real teacher sucks. I have to go back and re-read this it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This is Modus Tellens.

By truth table we could be able to see that the row in both $\neg q$ and $p\rightarrow q$ columns we have True(T), then we can conclude that this argument is valid.

The argument is valid.